# How to integrate Spring Batch ( without Spring Boot ) with Spring Cloud Data Flow Server

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-admin

We are running spring batch with jboss application server (therefore cant run it as spring boot app). Is there any integration options for monitoring/administering spring batch with Spring Cloud DataFlowServer for the spring batch running in Jboss container ?

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is an open issue to clarify this in the documentation: https://github.com/spring-io/dataflow.spring.io/issues/345.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was using spring batch with a weblogic 12.2.1.4 application server and wanted an admin console to view the status of job executions.  Spring Cloud Data Flow was not suitable for my requirement.  I ended up forking the old [spring-batch-admin](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-batch-admin) project and upgrading it to work with the latest version of spring batch and spring boot libraries.  My forked git repo is [here](https://github.com/httpants/spring-batch-admin).  I include this as a dependency in my war file that i deploy to weblogic and it provides the spring batch admin functionality, embedded in my application.

Comment: Thanks for the details.. I will have a look at your repo and provide my feedback.

Comment: It's probably worth also looking at https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin/blob/2.2.x/spring-batch-lightmin-documentation/src/main/doc/spring_batch_lightmin.html#_embedded_lightmin.  I'm not sure how you build your app, but for us we still use SpringBoot even though we build a war file that we deploy to weblogic.  So it may be possible for us to use lightmin (in embedded mode) to provide a spring batch admin console.  I'm going to look into this for our purpose.